# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize while running spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot

After chaning the spring-boot version to 2.0.1.RELEASE Getting this error while running spring boot project. I just change version from 2.0.3.RELEASE

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

[DEV: 2018-Dec-03 17:35:10,523][ERROR][main      ]Application run failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize
at org.springframework.boot.convert.StringToDataSizeConverter.getConvertibleTypes(StringToDataSizeConverter.java:40)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$Converters.add(GenericConversionService.java:507)
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.addConverter(GenericConversionService.java:105)
at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.addApplicationConverters(ApplicationConversionService.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.configure(ApplicationConversionService.java:91)
at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.<init>(ApplicationConversionService.java:52)
at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.<init>(ApplicationConversionService.java:45)
at org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService.getSharedInstance(ApplicationConversionService.java:71)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.configureEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:486)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:346)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
at org.onap.universalvesadapter.Application.main(Application.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: Please return and select @jugalmadhavan's answer. It is correct.

Answer (score 15):

This issue resolved for me because my POM.xml wrongly had the spring.version in properties tag.

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <kotlin.version>1.2.71</kotlin.version>
  <!-- <spring.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version> -->
</properties>
```

Answer (score 7):

Combining spring 4.x with spring-boot 2.1.x can cause this too.
Make sure that the `spring-core` dependency of `spring-boot` has the same version as your `spring-core` declaration on in your (parent) `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

according to [Spring Framework Versions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions)

JDK Version Range

- Spring Framework 5.1.x: JDK 8-12
- Spring Framework 5.0.x: JDK 8-10

So if you are using JDK 11, but in your pom.xml's you define:

```
<spring-framework.version>5.0.x.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
```

and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

then such issue happened. Of course, you can define spring-framework.version in another name or even comment it directly so you can bypass this version checking. But it's not recommended.

Solution:

Select proper spring-framework version to match your JDK.

Comment: I spent many hours today and finally. This is the actual solution and correctly diagnoses the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Never add spring-framework version inside properties tag of pom file. Let the spring boot decide which version of spring framework it needs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).